# Lotus Native Application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, lotus, lotus-domino

How can i make a lotus application an iPhone native apps?
For e.g: eLeave.

The submit or approve action button in the form was created using lotusscript. So how can it work in iOS ? I have no idea how can i extend my lotus application to an iPhone Native Apps. Someone had suggested to use either SOAP or REST via HTTP to communicate between iOS and domino. But i don't even know what can i do with SOAP in my apps.
Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions along the lines of SOAP or other HTTP-based access to the data are correct. Since you can't just port a Notes app to the iPhone (for a variety of reasons) or use the Notes Java API classes (since the iPhone doesn't have Java), some form of HTTP access is your best bet. Either traditional Domino web access via forms or XPages are most likely the best way to go, since then you can write your UI in Designer. If you don't want to or can't do that for whatever reason, you're on the hook for writing the UI for your iOS app separately and then connecting to Domino via Web Services or REST functionality.

SOAP Web Services are probably what you want. They have the advantage of being supported directly in Designer - you can create a Web Service Provider in LotusScript or Java in much the same way you would write an Agent or Script Library. You would have to write methods to access and update the data you want, but it would also mean you have full control over what happens. You could re-implement your form-submission code as a web service call that takes the changed data as parameters and then does whatever manipulation you want and creates/saves the document.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the version of Lotus/Domino you are running. This could be a start [XPages Mobile Controls](http://mobilecontrols.openntf.org/) I am not sure about the "native"here. This is XPages, web based.

Based on your comment, I know of one native application [TSAzr](http://www.tsazr.com/site.html). This application uses XPages as web-services on the domino server. A bit more info can be found here [dominoGuru](http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/tsazr_ls11_review.html)

Comment: My native apps here is something like user would able to download .ipa file for my lotus apps from applestore and one-time installed and can be access the apps straight away. Users are not going to access apps thru mobile web browser.

Comment: TSAzr's front-end is not written with XPages, FYI

Answer (score 0):

Your follow-up suggests that a mobile-optimised web application will not cut it, and that you want a native application. This means writing a new iOS application, end of story. There are different ways to go about this of course—e.g. you could build a web app and then wrapper it using something like Appcelerator Titanium, or PhoneGap—but ultimately, you need to write something.

As @Jesse Gallagher has already stated, Notes applications can't be ported directly to an iOS device. Apart from anything else, a Lotus Notes client application is a proprietary data store (NSF) sitting within a C and C++-based client built and compiled for the relevant underlying platform (Win or OS X). There is no direct analogue for iOS other than re-coding your app (of course, you could re-use the existing Lotusscript business logic via web service calls, as detailed in earlier answers).